# Q: baseline doesn't perfectly align in pNiceMatrix/bNiceMatrix

Tags: nicematrix

Is it possible to perfectly align the baseline of `p/bNiceMatrix`?
(The misalignment is quite obvious when you have a big matrix...)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    \rlap{\rule{57mm}{0.11pt}}0 = \begin{NiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
    \end{NiceMatrix}\quad
    0 = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}\quad
    0 = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 3 \\
        0 & 3 \\
        0 & 3 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Outcome

[image]

---

Thank you for all the replies.

Update: The patch suggested by @Ruixi Zhang solves the misalignment.

Update 2 (2021-11-26): There seems to be a side effect of the patch.

Test code

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
...
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{A table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
        \toprule
        a & b \\
        \midrule
        \Block{}{new\\line} & c \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: side effect]

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `[baseline =...]`.  In this example, removing `[baseline=2]` produces the correct alignment while `[baseline=1]`  does not.

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). I was not aware of that strange behaviour of the key `baseline`. At this time, I have no solution. I will investigate :-)

Comment: @F.Pantigny I doubt it’s the package’s fault. For odd number of rows, the alignment is already off in `array`. So anything built upon `array` will carry this defect. See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/147

Comment: Please try the updated fix :)

Comment: I will write a new version of `nicematrix` to correct that bug.

Comment: I'd suggest to post the follow-up newline in `\Block` problem as a new question. And, I can't reproduce it with `nicematrix` v6.4 2021/11/23 so a complete example is mostly welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version 6.4 of `nicematrix` (2021/11/23) solves that bug of `nicematrix`.

Here is a MWE.

Eventually, I don't use the Ruixi Zhang's patch of `{array}` of LaTeX (see other answer) because it seems that it has consequences when the command `\Block` is used with `\\` somewhere in the  matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \rlap{\rule{57mm}{0.11pt}}0 = \begin{NiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
    \end{NiceMatrix}\quad
    0 = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}\quad
    0 = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 3 \\
        0 & 3 \\
        0 & 3 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks! But now the `\Block{}{new\\line}` is broken... (with that patch). Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: @user8682688: That's strange. You should ask another question or send me directly a mail (you will find my address on the documentation of `nicematrix`).

Comment: It is not introduced by the new version (although the problem still exists). I have updated it in the question area above. (I meant the patch by Ruixi Zhang, sorry for the confusion!)

Answer (score 8):

This is a “dual” bug. The first part is in the LaTeX kernel itself and the second part is in the `nicematrix` package.

1. The first part of the bug is in the underlying `array` environment (and it’s been there since LaTeX2.09). I’ve reported this to the LaTeX team over two years ago (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/147). Any fixes *will* break backward compatibility, so the fixes are very unlikely to be implemented in the kernel.

   The problem is that each row of an `array` has a “strut”. This strut has a height-to-depth ratio of 7:3. But it should instead have a height of `<half baseline> + <math axis>` and a depth of `<half baseline> - <math axis>`. The difference is very small in most cases, but still visible enough to cause misalignment.

   For example, a `10pt` article with `12pt` baseline separation, set in Computer Modern Math, should have strut height 8.5pt and strut depth 3.5pt. But LaTeX sets strut height to about 8.4pt and strut depth to about 3.6pt, causing a tiny 0.1/2=0.05pt misalignment.
2. The second part of the bug is in the environment `NiceArrayWithDelims`. Even after we fix the kernel strut behavior, there is still a 0.4pt misalignment. The problem seems to be in `\vcenter{ \skip_vertical:N -\l_tmpa_dim ... \skip_vertical:N -\l_tmpb_dim }`. An offset of `\arrayrulewidth` seems to be missing.

   There is no easy way to patch LaTeX3 environment, so I will just copy the entire definition of `NiceArrayWithDelims` below. Only two lines of code are replaced. Thus, this fix is *not* to be taken seriously. It only serves as a temporary fix.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

% Fix the LaTeX kernel part of the bug
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % nicematrix loads array.sty
  \patchcmd\@array
    {\arraystretch \@tempdima}
    {\dimexpr\arraystretch\baselineskip/2
      +\arraystretch\extrarowheight
      +\fontdimen22\textfont\tw@\relax}
    {\typeout{Fixed array strut height for array.sty}}
    {\typeout{Couldn't patch \string\@array}}%
  \patchcmd\@array
    {\arraystretch \dp \strutbox}
    {\dimexpr\arraystretch\baselineskip
      -\arraystretch\baselineskip/2
      -\fontdimen22\textfont\tw@\relax}
    {\typeout{Fixed array strut depth for array.sty}}
    {\typeout{Couldn't patch \string\@array}}%
  \let\@@array\@array
}
\makeatother

% `Fix' the package bug.
% Only two lines are replaced!!!
% Not to be taken as a serious fix!!!
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { NiceArrayWithDelims }
  { m m O { } m ! O { } t \CodeBefore }
  {
    \bool_if:NT \c__nicematrix_revtex_bool \__nicematrix_patch_for_revtex:
    \__nicematrix_provide_pgfsyspdfmark:
    \bool_if:NT \c__nicematrix_footnote_bool \savenotes
    \bgroup
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__nicematrix_left_delim_tl { #1 }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__nicematrix_right_delim_tl { #2 }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__nicematrix_preamble_tl { #4 }
    \int_gzero:N \g__nicematrix_block_box_int
    \dim_zero:N \g__nicematrix_width_last_col_dim
    \dim_zero:N \g__nicematrix_width_first_col_dim
    \bool_gset_false:N \g__nicematrix_row_of_col_done_bool
    \str_if_empty:NT \g__nicematrix_name_env_str
      { \str_gset:Nn \g__nicematrix_name_env_str { NiceArrayWithDelims } }
    \__nicematrix_adapt_S_column:
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_NiceTabular_bool
      \mode_leave_vertical:
      \__nicematrix_test_if_math_mode:
    \bool_if:NT \l__nicematrix_in_env_bool { \__nicematrix_fatal:n { Yet~in~env } }
    \bool_set_true:N \l__nicematrix_in_env_bool
      \cs_gset_eq:NN \__nicematrix_old_CT@arc@ \CT@arc@
    \cs_if_exist:NT \tikz@library@external@loaded
      {
        \tikzexternaldisable
        \cs_if_exist:NT \ifstandalone
          { \tikzset { external / optimize = false } }
      }
    \int_gincr:N \g__nicematrix_env_int
    \bool_if:NF \l__nicematrix_block_auto_columns_width_bool
      { \dim_gzero_new:N \g__nicematrix_max_cell_width_dim }
    \seq_gclear:N \g__nicematrix_blocks_seq
    \seq_gclear:N \g__nicematrix_pos_of_blocks_seq
    \seq_gclear:N \g__nicematrix_pos_of_stroken_blocks_seq
    \seq_gclear:N \g__nicematrix_pos_of_xdots_seq
    \tl_gclear_new:N \g__nicematrix_code_before_tl
    \tl_gclear:N \g__nicematrix_row_style_tl
    \bool_gset_false:N \g__nicematrix_aux_found_bool
    \tl_if_exist:cT { c__nicematrix _ \int_use:N \g__nicematrix_env_int _ tl }
      {
        \bool_gset_true:N \g__nicematrix_aux_found_bool
        \use:c { c__nicematrix _ \int_use:N \g__nicematrix_env_int _ tl }
      }
     \tl_gclear:N \g__nicematrix_aux_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NF \g__nicematrix_code_before_tl
      {
        \bool_set_true:N \l__nicematrix_code_before_bool
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__nicematrix_code_before_tl \g__nicematrix_code_before_tl
      }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_NiceArray_bool
      { \keys_set:nn { NiceMatrix / NiceArray } }
      { \keys_set:nn { NiceMatrix / pNiceArray } }
    { #3 , #5 }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__nicematrix_rules_color_tl
      { \exp_after:wN \__nicematrix_set_CT@arc@: \l__nicematrix_rules_color_tl \q_stop }
    \IfBooleanTF { #6 } \__nicematrix_pre_array_i:w \__nicematrix_pre_array:
  }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_light_syntax_bool
      { \use:c { end __nicematrix-light-syntax } }
      { \use:c { end __nicematrix-normal-syntax } }
    \c_math_toggle_token
    \skip_horizontal:N \l__nicematrix_right_margin_dim
    \skip_horizontal:N \l__nicematrix_extra_right_margin_dim
    \hbox_set_end:
    \bool_if:NT \l__nicematrix_width_used_bool
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT \g__nicematrix_total_X_weight_int = 0
          { \__nicematrix_error:n { width~without~X~columns } }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT \g__nicematrix_total_X_weight_int > 0
      {
        \tl_gput_right:Nx \g__nicematrix_aux_tl
          {
            \bool_set_true:N \l__nicematrix_X_columns_aux_bool
            \dim_set:Nn \l__nicematrix_X_columns_dim
              {
                \dim_compare:nNnTF
                  {
                    \dim_abs:n
                      { \l__nicematrix_width_dim - \box_wd:N \l__nicematrix_the_array_box }
                  }
                  <
                  { 0.001 pt }
                  { \dim_use:N \l__nicematrix_X_columns_dim }
                  {
                    \dim_eval:n
                      {
                        ( \l__nicematrix_width_dim - \box_wd:N \l__nicematrix_the_array_box )
                        / \int_use:N \g__nicematrix_total_X_weight_int
                        + \l__nicematrix_X_columns_dim
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT \l__nicematrix_last_row_int > { -2 }
      {
        \bool_if:NF \l__nicematrix_last_row_without_value_bool
          {
            \int_compare:nNnF \l__nicematrix_last_row_int = \c@iRow
              {
                \__nicematrix_error:n { Wrong~last~row }
                \int_gset_eq:NN \l__nicematrix_last_row_int \c@iRow
              }
          }
      }
    \int_gset_eq:NN \c@jCol \g__nicematrix_col_total_int
    \bool_if:nTF \g__nicematrix_last_col_found_bool
      { \int_gdecr:N \c@jCol }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT \l__nicematrix_last_col_int > { -1 }
          { \__nicematrix_error:n { last~col~not~used } }
      }
    \int_gset_eq:NN \g__nicematrix_row_total_int \c@iRow
    \int_compare:nNnT \l__nicematrix_last_row_int > { -1 } { \int_gdecr:N \c@iRow }
    \int_compare:nNnT \l__nicematrix_first_col_int = 0
      {
        \skip_horizontal:N \col@sep
        \skip_horizontal:N \g__nicematrix_width_first_col_dim
      }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_NiceArray_bool
      {
        \str_case:VnF \l__nicematrix_baseline_tl
          {
            b \__nicematrix_use_arraybox_with_notes_b:
            c \__nicematrix_use_arraybox_with_notes_c:
          }
          \__nicematrix_use_arraybox_with_notes:
      }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l__nicematrix_first_row_int = 0
          {
            \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_dim \g__nicematrix_dp_row_zero_dim
            \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpa_dim \g__nicematrix_ht_row_zero_dim
          }
          { \dim_zero:N \l_tmpa_dim }
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l__nicematrix_last_row_int > { -2 }
          {
            \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_dim \g__nicematrix_ht_last_row_dim
            \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpb_dim \g__nicematrix_dp_last_row_dim
          }
          { \dim_zero:N \l_tmpb_dim }
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
          {
            \c_math_toggle_token
            \tl_if_empty:NF \l__nicematrix_delimiters_color_tl
              { \color { \l__nicematrix_delimiters_color_tl } }
            \exp_after:wN \left \g__nicematrix_left_delim_tl
            \vcenter
              {
%                \skip_vertical:N -\l_tmpa_dim
                \skip_vertical:n { -\l_tmpa_dim - \arrayrulewidth }
                \hbox
                  {
                    \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_NiceTabular_bool
                      { \skip_horizontal:N -\tabcolsep }
                      { \skip_horizontal:N -\arraycolsep }
                    \__nicematrix_use_arraybox_with_notes_c:
                    \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_NiceTabular_bool
                      { \skip_horizontal:N -\tabcolsep }
                      { \skip_horizontal:N -\arraycolsep }
                  }
%                \skip_vertical:N -\l_tmpb_dim
                \skip_vertical:n { -\l_tmpb_dim + \arrayrulewidth }
              }
            \tl_if_empty:NF \l__nicematrix_delimiters_color_tl
              { \color { \l__nicematrix_delimiters_color_tl } }
            \exp_after:wN \right \g__nicematrix_right_delim_tl
            \c_math_toggle_token
          }
        \bool_if:NTF \l__nicematrix_delimiters_max_width_bool
          {
            \__nicematrix_put_box_in_flow_bis:nn
              \g__nicematrix_left_delim_tl \g__nicematrix_right_delim_tl
          }
          \__nicematrix_put_box_in_flow:
      }
    \bool_if:NT \g__nicematrix_last_col_found_bool
      {
        \skip_horizontal:N \g__nicematrix_width_last_col_dim
        \skip_horizontal:N \col@sep
      }
    \bool_if:NF \l__nicematrix_Matrix_bool
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT \c@jCol < \g__nicematrix_static_num_of_col_int
          { \__nicematrix_error:n { columns~not~used } }
      }
    \group_begin:
    \globaldefs = 1
    \__nicematrix_msg_redirect_name:nn { columns~not~used } { error }
    \group_end:
    \__nicematrix_after_array:
    \egroup
    \iow_now:Nn \@mainaux { \ExplSyntaxOn }
    \iow_now:Nn \@mainaux { \char_set_catcode_space:n { 32 }  }
    \iow_now:Nx \@mainaux
      {
        \tl_gset:cn { c__nicematrix_ \int_use:N \g__nicematrix_env_int _ tl }
          { \exp_not:V \g__nicematrix_aux_tl }
      }
    \iow_now:Nn \@mainaux { \ExplSyntaxOff }
    \bool_if:NT \c__nicematrix_footnote_bool \endsavenotes
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    \rlap{\rule{57mm}{0.11pt}}0 = \begin{NiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 1 \\
        \rlap{\color{red}\rule{5.7mm}{0.11pt}}0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
    \end{NiceMatrix}\quad
    0 = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 2 \\
        \rlap{\color{red}\rule{5.7mm}{0.11pt}}0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}\quad
    0 = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
        0 & 3 \\
        \rlap{\color{red}\rule{5.7mm}{0.11pt}}0 & 3 \\
        0 & 3 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

The code inside `\AtBeginDocument{...}` is extracted from my own patch file (https://github.com/RuixiZhang42/font-pairing-guide/blob/master/mtpro2-patch.tex), lines 852–866 as of this writing. It covers only `array.sty`. A more thorough fix is provided as the code from line 850 to line 911.

Comment: That's very interesting. However, I think that there is also a bug in `nicematrix` related in the key `baseline`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Found it! This is indeed a dual bug (one in the kernel and one in the package). Misalignment happens when using `baseline` key *and* using delimited matrix. After fixing the kernel bug, the first OP example is correct, but the second and the third remain unfixed. The offset seems exactly `\arrayrulewidth`, so the problem lies within `\endNiceArrayWithDelims`.

Comment: +1: Impressive answer and thanks for your efforts

Comment: I will write a new version of `nicematrix` to correct that bug.

Comment: Hi @RuixiZhang, your patch works very well :) But... it seems that the `\Block{}{new\\line}` has also been affected (you can see the updates above). Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer, but only a possible `\patchcmd` way to patch the (end of) LaTeX3 environment `NiceArrayWithDelims`, in order to shorten the corresponding part of the "complete code" example from [@RuixiZhang's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623369).

```tex
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% patch \cs{environment NiceArrayWidthDelims end aux }
\char_set_catcode_space:n {32} % restore catcode of space char

\expandafter\patchcmd
  \csname environment~ NiceArrayWithDelims~ end~ aux~ \endcsname
  {\skip_vertical:N -\l_tmpa_dim}
  {\skip_vertical:n {-\l_tmpa_dim -\arrayrulewidth }}
  {}{\fail}

\expandafter\patchcmd
  \csname environment~ NiceArrayWithDelims~ end~ aux~ \endcsname
  {\skip_vertical:N -\l_tmpb_dim }
  {\skip_vertical:n {-\l_tmpb_dim +\arrayrulewidth }}
  {}{\fail}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

Comment: I tried the `\expandafter\patchcmd \csname environment~ NiceArrayWithDelims~ end~ aux~ \endcsname` trick but it didn't work: I was missing the `\char_set_catcode_space:n {32}` part...

Comment: @RuixiZhang It's `xpatch`'s `\tracingpatches` that helps me find the catcode issue of space.

Comment: Very nice detective work! Although, at the end, `\csname environment~ NiceArrayWithDelims~ end~ aux~ \endcsname` is `xparse`'s hidden/private/internal definition, and is subject to change without notice. Sigh... not an elegant fix no matter how hard we tried... :(

Comment: I remember there was a feature request asking for commands to patch latex3 (or xparse) cmds & envs, but can't find it after some search queries (in both latex2e and latex3's repo).

Comment: I will write a new version of `nicematrix` to correct that bug.